# Drawing lines to connect objects in Processing

Tags: processing, draw, lines

I'm doing a project that uses the ReactiVision framework and Processing for the graphical interface. Currently the code detects the fiducials, creates a square in its place and also shows the fiducial ID:

[Detecting fiducials](http://cl.ly/image/172u3a1c3q3A)

There is more code that constantly refreshes the screen. What I want is to connect each fiducial that is detected on the screen with a line. See the picture below:

[Drawing lines between fiducial shapes](http://cl.ly/image/2D0q1H3X0P04)

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I would really appreciate it! Please let me know if I'm not explaining this properly.

```
     pushMatrix();
     translate(tobj.getScreenX(width),tobj.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tobj.getAngle());
     rect(-obj_size/2,-obj_size/2,obj_size,obj_size);
     popMatrix();
```

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble? You'll have much better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that only includes stuff directly related to your question. Are you just asking how to connect 3 points with lines? What does that have to do with the fiducial stuff?

Comment: 'pushMatrix();
     translate(tobj.getScreenX(width),tobj.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tobj.getAngle());
     rect(-obj_size/2,-obj_size/2,obj_size,obj_size);
     popMatrix();'

This is the bit that draws the square ^

For my project I will have several fiducials that can be detected (up to 8) so let's say there are 4 fiducials that are being read, then there will be four lines connecting each fiducial, if there are 8, then there will be 8 lines connecting the fiduicals.
I need help with coding the line, as the screen is constantly refreshing and the fiducials can be moved at any point.

Comment: Can you post that code in your question? Your code should be small enough that we can copy and paste it to run it, but it should include the basics of your problem. Otherwise it's pretty impossible to help you, hence your lack of answers so far.

Comment: Well I have just shortened it to the bare minimum. There's no problem in the code. I would just like someone to help me/point me in the right direction to drawing connecting lines between each fiducial. Any help appreciated!